# Javascript Embeding WeekNum to my Calendar

Tags: javascript, html

i have problem with embedding week number into my calendar with JavaScript.
What will be the best way to put KW in my calendar with JavaScript. I have these function for finding current Week.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO9pe.png)

```
            function weekNum(date)
            {
                var tdt = new Date(date.valueOf());
                var dayn = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7;
                tdt.setDate(tdt.getDate() - dayn + 3);
                var firstThursday = tdt.valueOf();
                tdt.setMonth(0, 1);
                if (tdt.getDay() !== 4) 
                    {
                      tdt.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - tdt.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
                    }
                     return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - tdt) / 604800000);
                    }
                date = new Date();
                document.getElementById("current-week").innerHTML = "KW: " + weekNum(date);
```

And these is how i manually put KW in HTML

```
        <div class="label">
        <div class="vcal-weeknum">
            <span>KW</span>
        </div>          
        <div class="vcal-week">             
            <span>Pon</span>
            <span>Uto</span>
            <span>Sri</span>
            <span>Čet</span>
            <span>Pet</span>
            <span>Sub</span>
            <span style="color: #d2232b">Ned</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="date">  

        <div class="vcal-body-kw">
        <div class="vcal-date-kw vcal-week--active" data-calendar-date=""><span>5</span></div>
        <div class="vcal-date-kw vcal-week--active" data-calendar-date=""><span>6</span></div>
        <div class="vcal-date-kw vcal-week--active1" data-calendar-date=""><span>7</span></div>
        <div class="vcal-date-kw vcal-week--active" data-calendar-date=""><span>8</span></div>
        <div class="vcal-date-kw vcal-week--active" data-calendar-date=""><span>9</span></div>
        </div>      

        <div class="vcal-body" data-calendar-area="month"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to put KW in my calendar automatically with JavaScript. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we need some additional information.  You don't explain what "KW" means, and I see no reference to how the rest of your calendar is being rendered -- do you have JavaScript that already fills in the rest of your calendar days, or are you using a third party calendar?

Comment: Hay willman, i did resolve my problem. Thx for help